# Function is Continuous iff it is either constant or finite-to-one

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm working on a problem that says "Let $X$ be a topological space with a 'finite complement' topology, so that a set $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $X\setminus U$ is finite or $U=\varnothing$.  Prove that a map $f:X\to X$ is continuous iff it is either constant or finite-to-one. Something is finite-to-one if $\forall y\in Y$, $|f^{-1}(y)|<\infty$."

I managed to show the forward direction, that is, if $f:X\to X$ is continuous, then $f$ is either constant or finite-to-one.  It's the converse direction I'm having trouble with.  I'm trying to prove the contrapositive of the statement, that is, I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is discontinuous, then it is not constant and it is not finite-to-one.

When doing this, it's clear that $f$ can't be constant, since it's discontinuous, but I don't know how to show it's not finite-to-one.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Definition: $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}V$ is open in $ X$ whenever $V$ is open in $Y.$ It is simple to show that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}W$ is closed in $X$ whenever $W$ is closed in $Y.$ There are several equivalents to the def'n of continuity; some are better suited to some Q's than others. BTW you have an error in your 2nd line. It should say $U\subset X$ is open iff $(U=\phi$ or $X$ \ $U$ is finite). People are always overlooking the case of the empty set (because it's hard to see it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is discontinuous, then there is a closed subset $C$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}[C]$ is not closed. Then $\emptyset \neq C\neq X$ (since $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $f^{-1}[X]=X$, both of which are closed). So, $C$ is non-empty finite (the only other type of closed set) and $f^{-1}[C]$ is infinite. But then, for some $x\in C$, $f^{-1}[\{x\}]$ must be infinite too, by the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of seeing that is the following. Suppose that $f$ is not constant, nor finite to one. Then there exists $y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ has an infinite number of elements. But since $f$ is not constant, there existe $x\in X$ such that $x \notin f^{-1}(y)$. Now consider the open set $U=X\backslash \{y\}$. Then $A:=f^{-1}(U)$ is not empty (because it contains $x$) and its complementary is the infinite set $f^{-1}(y)$, so $A$ is not open, thus $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Isn't the complement of −1()  a subset of −1() rather the entire set? In which case the conclusion doesn't necessarily follow.

Comment: Nop. If A and B are two sets, $f^{-1}(A\backslash B)=f^{-1}(A)\backslash f^{-1}(B)$. Therefore $f^{-1}(U)=X\backslash f^{-1}(y)$.